# Can't add jenkins-job-builder in jenkins docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-job-builder

I'm new in docker. I want to create a docker container with Newman, Jenkins, Jenkins-job-builder. Please help me.

I built a docker image which bases on official Jenkins image https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins.

I used DockerFile. The build was successful, Jenkins app also runs successfully.

After running Jenkins I opened container as root 
`docker exec -u 0 -it jenkins bash` and tryed to add new job with jenkins-job-builder

`jenkins-jobs --conf ./jenkins_jobs.ini update ./jobs.yaml`

but I got `bash: jenkins-jobs: command not found`

There is my Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins
USER root
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN npm install -g newman
RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
RUN python get-pip.py
RUN pip install --user jenkins-job-builder
USER jenkins
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. :) What exactly do you mean by "jenkins-jobs command"? AFAIK, there is no such executable like this. What do you want to do from inside the container? Also, your Dockerfile doesn't seem to be complete, as `FROM` is missing, but as you said the build was successful, I guess it was a typo...?

Comment: Thank you, I've updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building your image, you get some warnings. Especially this one is interesting:

```
WARNING: The script jenkins-jobs is installed in '/root/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Simply remove the `--user` flag from `RUN pip install --user jenkins-job-builder` and you're fine.